# Can maps from Google Maps be used in school presentation?

Tags: copyright, internet, fair-use

I'm doing a presentation for a class in college. Am I allowed to include images of Google Maps? To clarify, I'm not using the actual photographs or street views of google maps, just the street names. Is this allowed? I tried reading their terms of use but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using just the names, there is no issue - you can't copyright a fact.

If you are using actual images (you appear to say you are not, but you also asked "Am I allowed to include images of Google Maps) - then the answer is still yes within your usage case - provided you attribute them to Google.

If you look at [this link](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html)  it specifies that you are OK to use this in Reports and Presntations, Books which are not guidebooks and which have less then 5000 copies and presentations.   If you are using them online, you need to use the imbedded versions (ie you can't just screenshot them - you need to link to them).

If you are still unsure, you can contact streetview-academic@google.com to request specific permission.

Comment: I'm using the picture of the map but what I meant is I'm not using Street View or any other addition like how they sometimes have options to see signs of local businesses etc.

Comment: If its printed, and less then 5000 copies, and not for commercial use you should be fine.